# How to create a new extension in typo3 6?

Tags: typo3

How to create a new extension in typo3 6?
Is the kickstarter extension compatible with typo3 6?

Comment: I agree, for now that are the right documents. "extension_builder"
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the extension "extension_builder". It generates (skeletons for) extbase/fluid based extensions and is compatible with TYPO3 6.0 (Makes even use of namespaces in generated extensions, which were only introduced in 6.0).

If you want to build fluid/exbase extensions, you should read [this](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/) book to get familiar with these extensions. In german it is also available as paperback.

I'm not sure the "kickstarter" extension still works, but its last update is a maintainance release to make it work in TYPO3 v4.6, so there is a good chance it does.

Answer (score 0):

**Q: How to create a new extension in typo3 6?**
A: There are two ways to create a new extension in typo3 6.

- The first way is described in this post: [See accepted answer on this
  page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905630/how-to-create-a-new-extension-in-typo3-6/14905790#14905790). It is a point and click user interface. You have to install the [extension "extension_builder"](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder)
- The second way is via command line. It is described here: ["Generating a Provider extension"](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/templating/provider-extension/generating-extensions.html).

Simple example for the second way of creating an extension:

1. Log into your typo3 v6.2 project
2. Install [extension "builder"](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/builder)
3. Open a shell
4. cd to document root of your typo3 project
5. type in this command to create an extension with the extension key "test":

   ./typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh extbase builder:providerextension \
       --extension-key test --author "Your name your@email.tld" \
       --pages 1 --content 1 --controllers 1 --git 1 --travis 1 --use-vhs 1
6. Fire up your php editor and go to path_to_your_typo3_project/typo3conf/ext/test and edit your brand new extension.
7. For more information visit https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/templating/provider-extension/generating-extensions.html

**Q: Is the kickstarter extension compatible with typo3 6?**
A: No. But the "old" pi-based extensions, you create with the kickstarter will still run on typo3 6.